# Expected &str found char with rust?

Tags: string, rust, char

I am getting this error

> expected `&str`, found `char`

For this code

```
// Expected output
// -------
// h exists
// c exists

fn main() {
    let list = ["c","h","p","u"];
    let s = "Hot and Cold".to_string();
    let mut v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in s.split(" ") {
        let c = i.chars().nth(0).unwrap().to_lowercase().nth(0).unwrap();
        println!("{}", c);
        if list.contains(&c) {
            println!("{} exists", c);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `list` from an array of `&str`s to an array of `char`s:

```
let list = ['c', 'h', 'p', 'u'];
```

Double-quotes `""` create string literals, while single-quotes `''` create character literals. See [Literal Expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/literal-expr.html) in the Rust reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a `list` to be a list of `char`s not a list of `str`s, in that case try changing

```rust
let list = ["c","h","p","u"];
```

to

```rust
let list = ['c','h','p','u'];
```

and it should work

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bca78058c5e52dafc8c424eae65d2261)